# Jmeter send email status update

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am completely new to Jmeter.

In my company we are  using Jmeter to analyze the performance of our application. The Jmeter has to run continuously, some SLA is dependent on the Jmeter.

Some times due Jmeter stops running. We cant have some one monitoring this task. I am looking at a option where the Jmeter will send an email update every 1 hour on the current status.  However I am not able to find any details on that. It would be great if some one share details on whether thats possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is use JMeter's [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) in separate Thread Group which will trigger every hour or via [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)

However if you need more control and additional extra information on running threads, uptime and need more control on your mail message you can use [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for it.

Reference Beanshell code to send email message:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

Properties mailprops = new Properties();
mailprops.put("mail.smtp.host", props.get("mail.host"));
mailprops.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
MailAuthenticator mailauth = new MailAuthenticator(props.get("mail.username"), props.get("mail.password"));
mailprops.put("mail.smtp.sumbitter", mailauth.getPasswordAuthentication());
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailprops, mailauth);
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(props.get("mail.username"));
message.setFrom(from);
for (String recipient : props.get("email").split(",")) {
    InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress(recipient);
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
}

message.setSubject("Any reasonable subject for " + new Date());
message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Anything you would like to include in your email");
message.setContent(sb.toString(), "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
Transport.send(message);
```

Both approaches assume external SMTP server being present and configured (you can use any public one)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your code and I get an error:

    Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import javax.mail.Message; import javax.mail.Session; import javax.mail.Transpor . . . '' : Method Invocation mailprops.put

any idea? couldn't find a good answer anywhere.

Comment: Why not to use [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)? Beanshell code is given as a reference for those who are familiar with Beanshell and/or Java. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) guide for detailed instructions

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something I can't do with the sampler. I've created a variable that saying whether the test succeeded  or failed and I want to send the email to specific recipient only if failed. by the way - I'm using BeanShell Sampler.

Comment: You can use [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to check whether you should send email or not. In any case, better to raise another question as this discussion becomes too long